# Formula for sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am so confused about the following problem (maybe I have made some silly conceptual mistakes)
The reference I used is Lee's introduction to Riemannian manifold.
[image]

There are two theorems in this book.

[image]
[image]

According to my understanding, the sectional curvature is a scalar, which can be computed by any basis of the tangent space by formula in theorem 8.29 (i.e. does not depend on the basis). Now, in exercise 8.30, $\lambda$ is a constant, substitute it into theorem 7.30 shows $f$ is a constant.

Then it seems (7.44) and (7.46) give different answers. 7.44 and 8.29 implies $\tilde{sec}(\Pi)=\lambda sec(\pi)$ while (7.46) implies $\tilde{sec}(\Pi)=\lambda^{-1} sec(\pi)$. How can this happen?

Does anyone have any ideas or comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying $(7.44)$ with constant $f$ shows that $\widetilde{\text{Rm}}=\lambda\cdot\text{Rm}$. So, by using formula $(8.28)$, we get that for a plane $\Pi$ spanned by two linearly independent vectors $v,w$,
\begin{align}
\widetilde{\text{sec}}(\Pi)&=\frac{\widetilde{\text{Rm}}(v,w,w,v)}{|v\wedge w|_{\widetilde{g}}^2}=\frac{\lambda\cdot \text{Rm}(v,w,w,v)}{\lambda^2\cdot|v\wedge w|_g^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\cdot\text{sec}(\Pi),
\end{align}
which is exactly what is claimed. I think you forgot to account for the different norm in the denominator.

Comment: LOL I see. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zorualyh oh another thing I should say is that I don’t see why you’re even mentioning formula $(7.46)$. That is talking about the scalar curvature, not the sectional curvature (keep in mind that knowledge of sectional curvature is equivalent to knowledge of the full curvature tensor. But the scalar curvature is just some traced information… i.e except for some special cases, you’re going to lose information).

Comment: I am not quite sure. The book I used defines the sectional curvature as $\frac{1}{2}S$ where $S$ is the scalar curvature. (The orginal sentence is like: define the section to be the intrinsic Gaussian Curvature at $p$, where the Gaussian curvature is defined as $K = 1/2 S$. )

Comment: @Zorualyh No, you’re misunderstanding Lee. The sectional curvature of a plane is (as Lee defines it) the Gauss-curvature of the **surface** $\text{exp}(\Pi\cap V)$, where $V$ is an open set on which $\text{exp}_p$ is a diffeomorphism. And yes, for a 2-dimensional manifold, the Gauss-curvature $K$, sectional curvature $A$ and scalar curvature $S$ are related by $S=2K=2A$, but this is only for 2-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: Just think for a moment: knowing scalar curvature $S$ means at each point $p\in M$, you need to know just a single number $S(p)$. Obviously this cannot be the same amount of information as the full curvature tensor $R^a_{bcd}(p)$, or knowledge of *all* sectional curvatures $\text{sec}(\Pi)$. In two dimensions, there is only one plane, which is why things simplify nicely. In higher dimensional manifolds, the scalar curvature is a certain sum of sectional curvatures (see proposition 8.32).

Comment: I see. Thanks for your detailed explanation!